# Was bedeutet »Du hast echt an alles gedacht«?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Ich würde gerne wissen, was es bedeutet, wenn jemand »*Du hast echt an alles gedacht*« sagt. Ich habe ein Bild gezeichnet und jemand hat das geschrieben. Es macht keinen Sinn das auf Englisch zu schreiben, besonders bei einem Bild. Ich übersetze das nämlich als:

> You thought of everything.

Kann jemand mir bitte sagen, was der Satz wirklich bedeutet?

Comment: Manche Leute sagen "echt" wenn sie "wirklich" meinen, zB Das ist echt gut. Das ist aber regionaler Sprachgebrauch und in der Standardsprache nicht üblich.

Comment: @rogermue: Und das macht jetzt echt einen Unterschied? Beides ist überflüssiges Füllworteln, außer für die, die gewohnheitsmäßig lügen, die müssen wohl dazusagen, dass sie meinen was sie sagen - nur wird diese Aussage selbst wohl wieder meist gelogen sein. :)

Comment: Mir ist unklar, was hier gefragt ist. Insbesondere glaube ich nicht, dass es um das Wort 'echt' geht. Was hat das mit einem Bild zu tun? Was mit Ausdrucksformen und Floskeln des Englischen? Wieso passt die englische Übersetzung nicht?

Comment: @user unkown: Im originalen Post wurde das deutlicher. Hubert Schölnast hat die Frage und meine Antwort editiert. Für OP ist Deutsch eine Fremdsprache und fragte unter anderem auch nach einer Korrektur seiner Fehler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auf Deutsch macht der Satz nicht viel mehr Sinn als auf Englisch.

> You **really** thought of everything.

Da ich das Bild nicht kenne, kann ich nur Annahmen treffen. Ich denke, dass du entweder äußerst detailliert gezeichnet hast und deswegen *alles* da ist. Oder du hast einen Sachverhalt dargestellt, der auch *alle* Ausnahmefälle zeigt, die - möglicherweise - normalerweise weggelassen werden.

Answer (score 3):

It means simply **You haven't forgotten anything**. You haven't forgotten any detail on your picture, everything is there, full of details.

This:

> an etwas denken

means in German *also* **to remember something**, for example

> *Denk daran, Blumen zu gießen!* = Remember to water the flowers.

Comment: The more common way to indicate the infinitive would be "an etwas denken". Ansonsten volle Zustimmung (und man könnte fast sagen, dass sich speziell die Formulierung "Du hast an alles gedacht!"/"Du denkst an alles!" schon mehr oder weniger zu einer festen Redewendung verwandelt hat).

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Der OP hat sich extra die Mühe gemacht, hier im **Deutsch**-Forum eine Frage über einen Teilbereich der **Deutschen** Sprache in **Deutsch** zu schreiben. Laut deinem Profil sprichst du fließend **Deutsch**. Warum also antwortest du in einer Fremdsprache?

Answer (score 2):

"Du hast echt an alles gedacht !" ist ein erstaunter Ausdruck, den man als zähneknirschendes Kompliment verstehen kann, wenn sich jemand auf die unwahrscheinlichsten Ereignisse vorbereitet hat.

"Wenn wir nach Maritius fliegen, können wir sicher sein, dass unsere Taucherausrüstung durch den Zoll kommt ?"
"Ich habe hier eine schriftliche Bestätigung vom Zoll, dass sämtliche
 Dinge zollfrei sind".
"Haben wir auch nichts vergessen ?"
"Hier ist die Checkliste, die ich heute morgen durchgegangen bin".
"Was ist mit meiner Lieblingsbrill...?"
"Ist bereits drin."
"Was ist, wenn wir zu spät kommen ?"
"Wird nicht passieren. Es gibt keinen Stau, das Auto ist durchgecheckt und vollgetankt, der Parkplatz ist reserviert und wir haben 3 Stunden Reserve. Und selbst wenn wir zu spät kommen: Ich habe eine Ausnahmeregelung mit der Reisegesellschaft, dass wir die nächste Maschine bekommen".
"Was ist mit dem Hotel ?"
"Reserviert und bezahlt. Wir benutzen das hotelinterne Boot; falls das mal ausfällt, habe ich 3 weitere Bootsverleihe vorgemerkt und mich versichert, dass diese Boote vorrätig haben. Ich habe übrigens noch den Bootsführerschein gemacht und Reservekanister für Benzin sind an Bord."
"Falls draußen etwas passiert..."
"Das Boot hat eine Dekompressionskammer gegen Taucherkrankheit und Satellitentelefon. Wir beide haben Harpunen und Haifischabwehrspray, du kannst auch ein Kettenhemd gegen Haie benutzen, dass an Bord ist. An Bord befindet sich auch ein Set von Gegengiften".

"Du hast echt an alles gedacht !"